# Shell script running different on MacOS and Linux

Tags: bash, macos, ubuntu

I'm trying to run my shell script on Linux (Ubuntu).
It's running correctly on MacOS, but on Ubuntu it doesn't.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while true
do
   node Client/request -t 10.9.2.4 -p 4400 --flood
done
```

Ubuntu output this error for running: sh myScript.sh:

```
Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "do")
```

1. Why is there any difference between them, since both of them are running by Bash? How can I avoid future errors caused by their differences?
2. I tried `cat yourscript.sh | tr -d '\r' >> yournewscript.sh` as related question was suggested to do, and also `while [ true ]`.
   The command `hexdump -C util/runner.sh` result is:

   ```
   00000000  23 21 2f 75 73 72 2f 62  69 6e 2f 65 6e 76 20 62  |#!/usr/bin/env b|
   00000010  61 73 68 0d 0a 0d 0a 77  68 69 6c 65 20 5b 20 74  |ash....while [ t|
   00000020  72 75 65 20 5d 0d 0a 64  6f 0d 0a 20 20 20 6e 6f  |rue ]..do..   no|
   00000030  64 65 20 43 6c 69 65 6e  74 2f 72 65 71 75 65 73  |de Client/reques|
   00000040  74 20 2d 74 20 31 39 32  2e 31 36 38 2e 30 2e 34  |t -t 192.168.0.4|
   00000050  31 20 2d 70 20 34 34 30  30 20 2d 2d 66 6c 6f 6f  |1 -p 4400 --floo|
   00000060  64 0d 0a 64 6f 6e 65 0d  0a                       |d..done..|
   00000069
   ```

Comment: Perhaps we could help you better if you told us *what* problem you have with the script? ***How*** doesn't it work on Ubuntu? And are you sure it's a problem with Bash and not Node or the application it tries to run?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude you right, thanks! Edited. And I'm trying to run it by shell.

Comment: How do you transfer the script to the Ubuntu system, or what settings do you have in your editor when saving the file? I wonder because the script seems to have Windows line-endings (CR-LF, `"\r\n"`), and not POSIX line-endings (plain LF, `"\n"`). That might have something to do with your problem.

Comment: Oh and the hexdump you show doesn't match the script you show. There should be an empty line between the two first (the "she-bang" and the `while`).

Comment: `tr -d '\r' < yourscript.sh > yournewscript.sh` then `bash yournewscript.sh`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The shebang `#!` line at the top of your file tells that this is a *bash* script. But then you run your script with `sh myScript.sh`, therefore using the `sh` shell.

**The `sh` shell is not the same as the `bash` shell in Ubuntu, as [explained here](https://askubuntu.com/a/141932/863297).**

To avoid this problem in the future, you should call shell scripts using the shebang line. And also make sure to prefer *bash* over *sh*, because the *bash* shell is more convenient and standardized (IMHO). In order for the script to be directly callable, you have to set the executable flag, like this:

```
chmod +x yournewscript.sh
```

This has to be done only once (it's not necessary to do this on every call.)

Then you can just call the script directly:

```
./yournewscript.sh
```

and it will be interpreted by whatever command is present in the first line of the script.

Comment: Naming `bash` scripts with a `.sh` suffix doesn't help either

Comment: The name is unimportant. It matters how you execute it.

Comment: I agree it only matters how you execute it, but I meant that the OP naming the script with `.sh` is misleading... why not name it `spreadsheet.xls` and confuse the heck out of everyone?

Comment: @MarkSetchell: I understand.. in the last company I worked the shell scripts all had a `.sh` suffix, although they were bash-scripts. It didn't turn out to be a problem, because it was always clear that we are using the bash, and not sh. So I thought that was normal. What would be a good extension? Or no extension, just `./yournewscript`?

Comment: I mean, I always read `.sh` as "I am a shell script", and not as "I am an `sh` script".